# Facebook Parse getting expired dates from table

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I am working on a parse (Facebook) app. I have a table however I want to be able to get the expired events (aka events that occur after some date). What is the best way to do this. I didn't see a date documentation with Parse.

My thought from dynamo experience was to simply save it and compare the values but this is costly. Is there a more efficient way?

Any ideas / anyone done this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the greaterThan, greaterThanOrEqualTo, lessThan and lessThanOrEqualTo methods on Parse.Query, and pass in date objects.

I.e.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
query.lessThan("eventDate", new Date());
```

This query will get you all objects from the table "Event", whose column "eventDate" (a Date column) contains a date that is before the current date.